# How do I interpret this python dependency tree?

Tags: python, conda

We are using conda to maintain a python environment and I'd like to understand why **google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0** is being installed when the latest available version is https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/2.16.1/ and the latest vaailable version on conda-forge (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-cloud-bigquery) is 2.15.0

Here's a Dockerfile that builds our conda environment:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl gnupg -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN curl https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/gpgkeys/anaconda.asc | gpg --dearmor > conda.gpg && \
        install -o root -g root -m 644 conda.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg && \
        gpg --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg --no-default-keyring \
        --fingerprint 34161F5BF5EB1D4BFBBB8F0A8AEB4F8B29D82806 && \
        echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/debrepo/conda stable main" \
        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/conda.list

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN MINICONDA_VERSION=4.9.2 && \
        CONDA_VERSION='4.9.*' && \
        CONDA_DIR=/opt/conda && \
        curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_${MINICONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        /bin/bash Miniconda3-py37_${MINICONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh -f -b -p $CONDA_DIR && \
        rm Miniconda3-py37_${MINICONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --set auto_update_conda false && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --set show_channel_urls true && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --remove channels defaults && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --add channels main && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --set env_prompt '({name}) ' && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --append envs_dirs /opt/conda/envs/ && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --append pkgs_dirs /opt/conda/pkgs/ && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda update --quiet --yes --all conda="${CONDA_VERSION}" && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda config --system --append channels conda-forge  && \
        $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda create -n py3 python=3.8

RUN bash -c "source /opt/conda/bin/activate /opt/conda/envs/py3 && conda install \
                invoke \
                apache-beam \
                sh \
                pytest \
                pytest-xdist \
                ipython \
                behave \
                black \
                pylint \
                flake8 \
                jinja2 \
                tenacity \
                responses \
                tqdm \
                google-api-python-client \
                google-auth-oauthlib \
                google-cloud-monitoring \
                google-cloud-bigquery \
                google-cloud-storage \
                google-cloud-pubsub \
                google-cloud-secret-manager \
                ipdb \
                rope \
                pipdeptree"
```

I build it using `docker build . -t conda-env` and then use `pipdeptree` inside the container to give me my dependency tree for google-cloud-bigquery:

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  --entrypoint bash \
  conda-env \
  -c "source /opt/conda/bin/activate /opt/conda/envs/py3 && pipdeptree --packages google-cloud-bigquery"
```

which gives me this:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0
  - google-cloud-core [required: >=1.0.3,<2.0dev, installed: 1.6.0]
    - google-api-core [required: >=1.21.0,<2.0.0dev, installed: 1.25.1]
      - google-auth [required: >=1.21.1,<2.0dev, installed: 1.28.1]
        - cachetools [required: >=2.0.0,<5.0, installed: 4.2.1]
        - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.2.1, installed: 0.2.8]
          - pyasn1 [required: >=0.4.6,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.8]
        - rsa [required: >=3.1.4,<5, installed: 4.7.2]
          - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.8]
        - setuptools [required: >=40.3.0, installed: 52.0.0.post20210125]
        - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.15.0]
      - googleapis-common-protos [required: >=1.6.0,<2.0dev, installed: 1.53.0]
        - protobuf [required: >=3.12.0, installed: 3.14.0]
          - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.15.0]
      - protobuf [required: >=3.12.0, installed: 3.14.0]
        - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.15.0]
      - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2021.1]
      - requests [required: >=2.18.0,<3.0.0dev, installed: 2.25.1]
        - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2020.12.5]
        - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<5, installed: 3.0.4]
        - idna [required: >=2.5,<3, installed: 2.10]
        - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.4]
      - setuptools [required: >=40.3.0, installed: 52.0.0.post20210125]
      - six [required: >=1.13.0, installed: 1.15.0]
    - google-auth [required: >=1.24.0,<2.0dev, installed: 1.28.1]
      - cachetools [required: >=2.0.0,<5.0, installed: 4.2.1]
      - pyasn1-modules [required: >=0.2.1, installed: 0.2.8]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.4.6,<0.5.0, installed: 0.4.8]
      - rsa [required: >=3.1.4,<5, installed: 4.7.2]
        - pyasn1 [required: >=0.1.3, installed: 0.4.8]
      - setuptools [required: >=40.3.0, installed: 52.0.0.post20210125]
      - six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.15.0]
    - six [required: >=1.12.0, installed: 1.15.0]
  - google-resumable-media [required: >=0.3.1,<0.6.0dev,!=0.4.0, installed: 0.5.1]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.15.0]
  - protobuf [required: >=3.6.0, installed: 3.14.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.15.0]
```

I have to hold my hand up and admit I simply don't know how to interpret that. For example, does this:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0
  - google-cloud-core [required: >=1.0.3,<2.0dev, installed: 1.6.0]
```

mean that google-cloud-core is forcing google-cloud-bigquery to be ">=1.0.3,<2.0dev" or does it mean google-cloud-core is being forced by something else to be ">=1.0.3,<2.0dev". I basically don't understand that information being presented to me so I'm hoping someone can enlighten me. better still, if someone can tell me what I can do to get a later version of **google-cloud-bigquery** installed I'd be very grateful, because there are known bugs in 1.22.0.

Comment: Not digging very deep into this, but the dependency on Debian Stretch is likely to pin you to older versions of anything installed oy the OS. If you switch to `buster-slim`, do you get a newer version?

Comment: will give it a go

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but unfortunately bumping to `debian:buster-slim` didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question first:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0
  - google-cloud-core [required: >=1.0.3,<2.0dev, installed: 1.6.0]
```

means, that `google-cloud-bigquery` is installed with version 1.22.0, which requires `google-cloud-core` to be installed with a version between 1.0.3 and 2.0 and you have version 1.6.0 of it installed.

To check the constraints of `google-cloud-bigquery` - which you are probably trying to do, add the `--reverse` flag like that: `pipdeptree --reverse --packages google-cloud-bigquery`. The output isn't useful though, because "you're looking at the wrong side of the tree":

```
Warning!!! Possibly conflicting dependencies found:
* pylint==2.7.4
 - astroid [required: >=2.5.2,<2.7, installed: 2.5]
* flake8==3.9.0
 - pycodestyle [required: >=2.7.0,<2.8.0, installed: 2.6.0]
 - pyflakes [required: >=2.3.0,<2.4.0, installed: 2.2.0]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0
```

So to see the actual restraint, run `pipdeptree --reverse` and look for `google-cloud-bigquery`. Then you'll find, that `urllib3` in version 1.26.4 constraints `requests` to version 2.25.1, which constraints `google-api-core` to 1.25.1, which constraints `google-cloud-core` to 1.6.0, which constraints `google-cloud-bigquery` to 1.22.0.

If I had to guess, I'd say that one of those mentioned packages is already installed (EDIT: even before you're installing your specific packages) in their respective version, which leads to what you're seeing.

I ran `pip install google-cloud-bigquery --upgrade` on top of your build, which worked perfectly fine, so you could either run that at the end or just upgrade all packages before installing your specific stuff (which I'd personally recommend, updating your base is always a good idea. That being said, if your own constraints are "too old", that wouldn't work and you should fall back to upgrading after you've installed your specific stuff).

Comment: Hugely appreciate this fantastic response, taught me a lot. Thank you.